# How many words of length $n ≥ 4$ in the alphabet ${1, 2, 3}$ contain at least two $1$’s, at least two $2$’s, and at least two $3$’s?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

How many words of length $n ≥ 4$ in the alphabet ${1, 2, 3}$ contain at least two $1$’s, at least two $2$’s, and at least two $3$’s?

My approach involves the incluson-exclusion principle. If you let
$$S=\{\text{all words of length }n\}\\
A_i=\{\text{all words of length }n \text{ that do not contain two }i\text{'s}\},$$
where $1\leq i\leq3$, then our desired number is
$$|S-(\bigcup_{i=1}^3A_i)|$$
I am currently trying to figure out what $|A_i|, |A_i\cup A_j|$, and $|A_i\cup A_j \cup A_k|$are to evaluate this expression.  Here's my thoughts:
$$|A_i|=2^n+n2^{n-1}$$
because the word can either have 0 or 1 $i$. If you have zero $i$'s, then each of the $n$ letters in the word have two options. If you have one $i$ for which you can place in any of the $n$ places, and each of the $n-1$ terms have two options. I am unsure how to compute the others. Any help would be amazing!

Comment: Note:  if your word has exactly one letter $i$ then you have $n$ places to place that $i$, after which there are indeed $2^{n-1}$ ways to populate the other slots.

Comment: thank you! I have updated the question

Comment: Why $n \ge 4$ instead of $n \ge 6$?

Comment: Im not sure. This is the problem that was given to me, but I agree that it would be much simpler if the word had to be at least 6 letters

Comment: No, it is simple for $4$ and $5$ letters.  You just declare it to be $0$.  That will probably come out of your formula, but it is a good way to make sure people are careful.  There is nothing wrong with allowing this possibility in a problem.  It can also trip up people who just find a recurrence because the starting values may be $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inclusion-exclusion yields:
\begin{align}
&\quad\binom{3}{0}3^n\\
&-\binom{3}{1}\left(\binom{n}{0}2^{n-0}+\binom{n}{1}2^{n-1}\right)\\
&+\binom{3}{2}\left(\binom{n}{0}1^{n-0}+2\binom{n}{1}1^{n-1}+2\binom{n}{2}1^{n-2}\right)\\
&-\binom{3}{3}\left(\binom{3}{0}[n=0]+\binom{3}{1}[n=1]+2\binom{3}{2}[n=2]+3!\binom{3}{3}[n=3]\right) \\
&= 3^n\\
&-3\left(2^n+n2^{n-1}\right)\\
&+3\left(1+2n+n(n-1)\right)\\
&-\left([n=0]+3[n=1]+6[n=2]+6[n=3]\right) \\ 
&=
3^n
-3\cdot 2^n-3n2^{n-1}
+3+3n+3n^2
-\left([n=0]+3[n=1]+6[n=2]+6[n=3]\right)
\end{align}
If $n \ge 4$, this reduces to
$$3^n-3\cdot 2^n-3n2^{n-1}+3+3n+3n^2,$$
which correctly evaluates to $0$ for $n\in\{4,5\}$ and $90=\binom{6}{2,2,2}$ for $n=6$.

This is [OEIS sequence A224541](https://oeis.org/A224541).